# Why automator's component "Get Selected Finder Items" duplicates path of selected file?

Tags: terminal, finder, automator

I'm trying to make automator quick action/service for coping text from images.

It looks like this:

[image]

When I run script from automator everything works fine. But when I try to run it from services menu (`right click on image > Services > service_name`) then it doesn't work as expected.

The problem is that `"Get Selected Finder Items"` returns two copies of the to the image's path. In this case `~/Desktop/t1.png ~/Desktop/t1.png`. I even saved input to the script to a separate file (`foo.txt`) to be sure.

So the question is why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When run from the **Automator** app it needs the **Get Selected Finder Items** *action*, however when run as a *Quick Action* from **Finder** it isn't needed as the selected *files* in **Finder** are passed to the *Quick Action*.

You need to remove or disable the **Get Selected Finder Items** *action* to have the duplication stopped when run as a *Quick Action*.

To disable an *action*, check the **[√] Ignore this action's input** under the *action's* **Options**.